# How do I use placeholders with Class-based password reset views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

There are four such view :

`PasswordResetView` sends the mail # - `PasswordResetDoneView` shows a success message for the above # - `PasswordResetConfirmView` checks the link the user clicked and # prompts for a new password # - `PasswordResetCompleteView` shows a success message for the above. I want to use placeholders for them but there doesn't seem to be an option. Overwriting the class seems kinda overkill.

Comment: By placeholder, do you mean the templates? If so, you can just override them.

Comment: @Karl I did. But now the form fields aren't visible. Here's what i did: https://imgur.com/a/YPJSVrS

Comment: Can you post your templates? To override the templates, you only need to override the `template_name`, not the entire view/forms (unless you need to). See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) for more details on overriding the template.

Comment: Also, its best to keep your code snippets within your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can us Javascript to handle that in your front end.

OR

You can call the get_form method and manipulate the password input.

LIKE:

form.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder']="New placeholder"

Comment: Don't know Javascript. Any examples of the `get_form` usage?